# What's the story behind command file's suggestion?

Tags: history, file-command

While I'm reading `file(1)` I noticed this in the man page (emphasis mine):

> When adding local definitions to /etc/magic, make sure to preserve these keywords.
>    Users depend on knowing that all the readable files in a directory have
>    the word “text” printed. **Don't do as Berkeley did and change “shell
>    commands text” to “shell script”.**

What's the story behind this sentence? I guess `Berkeley` refers to `BSD (Berkeley software distribution)` but Google didn't give enough information about this.

Link to `file(1)` http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/file.1.html

Some digging around shows that this statement was added 27 years ago [link](https://github.com/glensc/file/blob/98cbbcf41a48a5d27c9c8839fa800f15b854ef33/doc/file.man)

```
Don't do as one computer vendor did \- change ``shell commands text''
to ``shell script''.
```

and later changed to current statement [link](https://github.com/glensc/file/commit/b6a6a64c)

```
Don't do as Berkeley did \- change ``shell commands text''
```

Answer (score 8):

People had been writing scripts (and possibly C programs) to run `file` on a file,
capturing the output with `$(file foobar)` or `popen()`,
and doing a string match check
to see whether the output from `file` contained (or ended with) the word “text”. 
Then the developers of the Berkeley Software Distribution
(at the University of California, Berkeley) did as described
and caused all those scripts and programs
*not* to recognize shell script files as text files.

Comment: When was this happened? Any reference?

Comment: It was probably in the late (very late) 1970s or the early 1980s. I can’t find a reference; I’m relaying my memory.

Comment: `not to recognize shell script files as text files`. shell script can contain binary data:) see: [Failing detection of shell scripts with embedded binary data](http://mx.gw.com/pipermail/file/2014/001380.html), [buggy magic: #!/bin/sh with embedded binary data reported as 'data'](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=707014), [Fix](https://github.com/file/file/commit/cf617ae866acbe976ebb301714799becc79f8de4)

Comment: @EvgenyVereshchagin: OK, that's sort of relevant to the topic — but not much.  Or are you making a point?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this happened between 4.2 and 4.3BSD -- compare http://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=4.2BSD/usr/src/usr.bin/file.c and http://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=4.3BSD/usr/src/usr.bin/file.c